# openpyxl hides new columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to read in a xlsx file and later made additions to it before saving it in a new file.

It used to work well on openpyxl 2.1.2 but after installing python on a new computer with the newest version of openpyxl it starts to hide all added columns.

I have tried adding:

```
ws.column_dimensions['A'].hidden = False
...
ws.column_dimensions['Z'].hidden = False
```

But that does not change anything.

Any ideas? Having to open up each spreadsheet generated just to unhide and save is kinda annoying.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl does not hide columns by default. If you think there is a problem then please submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade openpyxl version to 2.3 or later. I have same issue before, upgrade version solved my problem