# openpyxl hides two columns instead of 1

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here is a MRE. [Download "huge_bug.xlsx" (it's a wetransfer link)](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/89eff5d269cfc2a771dec590a7f3901020230301180308/23666a) first:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

document = load_workbook("huge_bug.xlsx")

# hide column AJ
document.active.column_dimensions["AJ"].hidden = True

# save workbook
document.save("huge_bug_2.xlsx")
```

I want to hide column `AJ` but both columns `AJ` and `AK` get hidden and I have no idea why. There is no merged cell that could indicate why those two columns "work together".

I suspect the problem is in my initial excel file, but I'm not sure where to look.

I'm using `openpyxl 3.0.10` and `Python 3.11.1`.

EDIT: As @moken pointed out, it probably has to do with the "fill" of the columns, if you change one of them, only by one point, the bug is not reproducible anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't consider code that requires a "huge download" to be a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And I'm definitely not clicking that link.

Comment: I believe t's an old bug of openpyxl [openpyxl hides new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675059/openpyxl-hides-new-columns)

Comment: @Woodford Why are you saying it's huge? it's 10 Kb???

Comment: Huge is for "huge bug" not for "huge download". Otherwise, you can just create a workbook with around 40 columns and one row and reproduce it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with a clean workbook with around 40 columns and one row. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1APQI.png Using `openpyxl 3.0.10` and `Python 3.9.7`

Comment: @BigBen so the problem does come from the excel workbook I have. i'm unable to identify why though. any idea?

Comment: Change the fill colour of one of the columns (AJ or AK) and it hides only column AJ. Even by the smallest change (I changed the RGB colour value Blue by 1 point). Make all columns not filled or filled with the same colour and both get hidden. Very strange.

Comment: The problem is in my whole pipeline, I don't handle the creation of this file. I could artificially temporarily change the colour of the fill of one of the columns but it feels like a bad fix.

Comment: Again you could use Xlwings, it hides the specified column AJ only, Col AK is untouched.

Comment: You can do a **document.active.column_dimensions["AK"].hidden = False** after the Col AJ hide and that works (for me anwyay) only thing is this also removes the fill colour in AK except for rows 1 and 2. I.e. the cells with text. If I add text to row 3 then this also retains the fill colour when AK hidden is set back to False.

Comment: I could unhide the column with openpyxl and use xlwings to re-add the fill colour, but that sounds like a bug that surely could be fixed, right, whether my initial .xlsx has something weird or openpyxl has a bug in their library. I understand using another library for a feature that doesn't exist, but using another library for a feature that's sort of broken and that might be easily fixed is less understandable from a code perspective (and a code optimisation perspective).

Comment: If your going to use Xlwings you may as well just use it just to hide Col AJ. However certainly it shouldn't be necessary to switch between libs. The sheet exhibits strange behaviour I can't guess how it appears related to fill or a style. You'd be better to follow up with the Openpyxl devs as you may well have a bug with Openpyxl.

Comment: Should I create an issue on their github?

Comment: Yes, that would ensure the devs see it.

Comment: https://github.com/theorchard/openpyxl/issues/24

Comment: @FluidMechanics Potential Flows  Sorry, I remember that Openpyxl uses Heptapod, so per the docs [Openpyxl Docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) use [issues](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues)  That github site is probably no good to you.

Comment: Ohh, well spotted. Here is the issue I've posted: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1988.